# installing nginx mainline with homebrew

Tags: osx, nginx, homebrew

Trying to install the mainline (1.11.x) version of nginx with homebrew with no success, is there a way ? (I found this http://brew.sh/homebrew-nginx/ but no mainline specific instructions).

Comment: Which version of OS X and which errors you get?

Comment: El Capitan. No error, I just don't how how to do it (it seems I can only get the stable line).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can see install options with `brew options nginx` :

```
--with-debug
Compile with support for debug log
--with-gunzip
Compile with support for gunzip module
--with-http2
Compile with support for the HTTP/2 module
--with-passenger
Compile with support for Phusion Passenger module
--with-webdav
Compile with support for WebDAV module
--devel
Install development version 1.11.5
--HEAD
Install HEAD version
```

To install the mainline version run:

```
brew install --devel nginx
```